# Effect of modifying a relation in Hybris

Tags: java, database, sap-commerce-cloud

I have an existing relation in Hybris. What would happen (possibly go wrong) if I modify the relation.

For eg-
What would happen if I add the ordered attribute to an existing relation.

```
<relation code="WishlistProductsRelation" generate="true" autocreate="true" localized="false">
            <deployment table="wishlistProductRel" typecode="26017" />
            <sourceElement qualifier="wishlists" type="Wishlist" collectiontype="list" cardinality="many">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" />
            </sourceElement>
            <targetElement qualifier="products" type="Product" collectiontype="set" cardinality="many" ordered="true">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" />
            </targetElement>
        </relation>
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on what you will exactly change.

In the database, nothing is ever removed when you make modifications, so data is not lost that way. A typical many to many relation table looks something like `PK;SourcePK;TargetPK`. As long as the sourcePK and targetPK remain valid for the new type, not much will happen.

Changing the **deployment variables** (typecode/table) will create a new table and you will lose your current data. But this allows you to start over fresh as if it was a new table.

Changing the **source** or **target** depends a bit to what you change them to. If the type inherits from the previous type (or is a parent type of the current type), for example if you would change Product to VariantProduct, all relations to variant products would remain existing. The other values, that are no longer valid will show empty values in the backoffice, but might throw exceptions when used in code. It's always advised to clear out invalid entries before updating the relation object

Changing **modifiers** will have no real consequences, same with the **CollectionType**, though with collection type, you might break some code that currently expects a list or a set

Changing from **many-to-many** to **one-to-many** will cause you to lose all your current data, as those types of relations are not stored in a separate deployment table.

Changing the **qualifier** of the source or target will only break the code (and possible existing queries) but will retain the data.